# Where is the adhoc request option in Airflow 2.0.1?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I do not see an adhoc request in the dropdown within airflow 2.0.1. Does anyone have info on this? Was it removed from 2.0+? Any help will be greatly appreciated, I used this a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ad-Hoc query was removed in Airflow 2.0.0 due to security reasons.

> Due to security concerns, the new webserver will no longer support the
> features in the Data Profiling menu of old UI, including Ad Hoc Query,
> Charts, and Known Events.

This is listed in [change log](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md#breaking-changes).

Comment: Thank you for the info Elad